# Mansonry Lib is not working

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am just trying to include mansonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/) into my wordpress installation but somehow it is not working at http://letpack.lukasoppler.ch/geschuetzte-arbeitsplaetze/werkstatt/

Can you give me some hints what i forgot to think about?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi, if you want an answer to this question, you need to provide details of what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried, what errors you've encountered etc, the information you've provided doesn't allow us to answer your question

Comment: ok let me explain more precise: 

1. I included the masonry.pkgd.min.js in the header
2. I adjusted the html structure (see the link obove and his image gallery)
3. I included the script 
<script type="text/javascript">
   // external js: masonry.pkgd.js
   $('.grid').masonry({
     itemSelector: '.grid-item',
     columnWidth: 160
   });
  </script>
in my header

All this you can check in the source code of the link i sent before. But somehow it is not working as described from the author.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you've missed out the css associated with the masonry plugin. If you check here http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html you'll see that you need to add something like

```
.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 2px solid hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Also there's an advanced version of this using isotope which I put on CodePen which you can see here http://codepen.io/jezemery/pen/aOWgjL

Comment: thank you for your quick  answer!
This I forgot to mention, i already included this css with "float:left;". In the beginning of the gallery on http://letpack.lukasoppler.ch/geschuetzte-arbeitsplaetze/werkstatt/ there is a white gap after the first image, this shoud disappear if mansonry is working i think

Comment: @Luke Your column width & the width defined in the css need to be the same ( or at least the columnWidth should be equal to or greater than the width of the element ) e.g. set the columnWidth to 160 and the width in the css to 160px

Comment: You can then use padding etc to separate things